# Linear optimization with R

Tags: r, optimization

I'm trying to maximize the function by x[1], x[2]:

`(a - 1) * x[1] * c + (a - 1) * x[2] * b * d`

Where a, b, c, d are known positive constants and

`0 < x[1] < 1, 0 < x[2] < 1,
x[1] + x[2] = 1`

Using NlcOptim, I did:

```
    solver_1 <- function(a, b, c, d){
  obj = function(x){
    return((a - 1) * x[1] * c + (a - 1) * x[2] * b * d )
  }
  con = function(x){
    f = NULL
    f = rbind(f, x[1] + x[2] - 1)
    return(list(ceq = f, c = NULL))
  }
  x0 = c(1, 0)

  solnl(x0, objfun = obj, confun = con)
}

solver_1(1.2, 5.2, 0.8, 0.1)
```

But it gives me:

```
 Error in if (norm(H, "I") == 0) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I don't think you can estimate `b` and `d` separately. Also, why don't you substitute `x[2] = 1 - x[1]` instead of defining a constraint?

Comment: @Roland If you get it down to 1 variable, then the other variable might take on values which violate the nonnegativity constraint. You could get it down to 1 variable, but then would need to add a constraint to keep the retained variable in acceptable bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Using an optimization package is massive overkill.

Either by following up on the comment of @Roland and doing some elementary calculus, or using the corner point theorem of linear programming, your objective function is optimized when `x[1] = 0` and `x[2] = 1` or vice versa. Thus you only have to evaluated two constant expressions in `a,b,c,d` and pick the larger of the two:

```
max(c*(a-1), b*d*(a-1))
```

For any `a` other than 1, which is larger will be determined by whether or not `c > a*b`

Comment: I have corrected the constraints function as following:
0 < x[1] < 1, 0 < x[2] < 1,
x[1] + x[2] = 1

Comment: @Amidavid Those is the constraints that I implicitly used. You are optimizing a linear function over the line segment connecting `(0,1)` and (`1,0)`. The optimum occurs at one of those two end points. The simplex algorithm isn't needed for that.

Comment: There are higher values for the function - for example, in the case of `x[1] = 0.93 , x[2] = 0.07`

Comment: @Amidavid It is impossible for a linear function to be optimized on a convex set at a point other than an extreme point. This fact is the basis of the simplex algorithm, which is a search among extreme points. Here you have two extreme points, and you already know what they are. Please provide values for `a,b,c,d` with the property that the optimum does not occur at an extreme point.

Comment: @Amidavid With the `a,b,c,d` in your code, the value of the objective function is `0.16` at `(1,0)` but `0.15608` at `(0.93, 0.07)`.  If you have the constraints that `x[1]` and `x[2]` are both strictly greater than 0, then no optimal solution exists since the closer `x[2]` is to `0`, the closer the function is to its least upper bound `0.16`.